# Python AutoGUI not clicking

Tags: bots, pyautogui

Hey I'm pretty bad at coding, but I wanted to automate a task in a game, specifically fishing. Therefore, you have to click a button, another one pops up with a white circle around it. This circle varies its size and when its the size of the button, the circle changes its color and you have to click the button to catch a fish. Therefore I searched the first button (fishing hole), and clicked on its position. Then I look at a specific pixel around the second button, that changes color from white to pale red?. If the color changes, I want to click the button. Everything works besides this last step, it moves there if I use the `pyautogui.click(x,y)`, but it doesn't click. Any way to make it work (bear in mind I'm not an experienced programmer)?. I tried `pyautogui.click(x,y)`, clicking several times and so on. Thank you.

```
import pyautogui as pa
import time

counter = 0

def main():
    global counter
    # Countdown to open the game
    for i in reversed(range(0,5)):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    
    # Finding the fishing hole using a prior screenshot
    fishing_hole_location = pa.locateOnScreen("fishing_hole.png",confidence = 0.5)
    
    # Getting the center of the hole
    fishing_hole_center = pa.center(fishing_hole_location)
    
    # Clicking the hole
    pa.click(fishing_hole_center[0], fishing_hole_center[1])

    
    time.sleep(3)

    # Locating the second button (even though it appears in the middle of the screen)
    fishing_button_location = pa.locateOnScreen("fishing_button.png",confidence = 0.5)

    # Finding the buttons center
    fishing_button_center = pa.center(fishing_button_location)

    while True:
        # Looking at the pixel at the edge of the button
        pix = pa.pixel(int(fishing_button_center[0]+24), int(fishing_button_center[1]))
        # If the pixel doesn´t have its usual colour 5 times in a row, I want to click the button
        if pix != (75,99,118):
            counter+= 1
            if counter >= 5:
                pa.moveTo(fishing_button_center[0], fishing_button_center[1])
                time.sleep(2)
                pa.click()
                break
        else:
            counter = 0
        time.sleep(0.1)


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making a function like this instead of using the pre-built one -

```
def click(button):
    pyautogui.mouseDown(button=button)
    pyautogui.mouseUp(button=button)
```

It worked for me when I had this same problem